# JQuery - sum check boxes values according parent class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have script that sum all checked checkboxs, but I would like to sum only checkboxs values where parent div has class="show_list_item"

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function (){
  var total_srvs_amount = 0;
  $('input[name="amount"]:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
    total_srvs_amount += isNaN($(this).val()) ? 0 : parseInt ($(this).val());   
    console.log(total_srvs_amount);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show_list_item">
       <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="100">
       <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="120">
</div>
<div class="hide_list_item">
       <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="85">
       <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="90">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the selector to apply the function on checkboxes inside `.show_list_item`:

```js
$('.show_list_item input:checkbox').change(function ()
{
    var total_srvs_amount = 0;
    $('.show_list_item input[name="amount"]:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
        
        total_srvs_amount += isNaN($(this).val()) ? 0 : parseInt ($(this).val());
        
        console.log(total_srvs_amount);

    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show_list_item">
   <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="100">
   <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="120">
</div>
<div class="hide_list_item">
   <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="85">
   <input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="90">
</div>
```